# Telegram API - editMessageText seems doesn't work with messages containing Custom Keyboard. Why?

Tags: json, post, get, telegram

I'm building Telegram Bot based on POST/GET JSON queries having custom Keyboard. In some action I need to change the text of the message sent by bot, using editMessageText method.
The problem is everything works fine if the message from bot was just with text, but editing the text doesn't work with messages containing custom keyboard.

For example,
If the bot sends the message:
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-}/sendMessage?chat_id={-Variable.CHAT_ID-}&text=BLA_BLA](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7B-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-%7D/sendMessage?chat_id=%7B-Variable.CHAT_ID-%7D&text=BLA_BLA)

this GET-query doing editing the text successfully:
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-}/editMessageText?chat_id={-Variable.CHAT_ID-}&message_id={-Json.result.message_id-}&text=EDITED_BLA_BLA](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7B-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-%7D/editMessageText?chat_id=%7B-Variable.CHAT_ID-%7D&message_id=%7B-Json.result.message_id-%7D&text=EDITED_BLA_BLA)

But once the source message contains custom keyboard (same code just witn reply_markup at the end):
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-}/sendMessage?chat_id={-Variable.CHAT_ID-}&text=BLA_BLA&reply_markup={Some_Keyboard}](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7B-Variable.BOT_TOKEN-%7D/sendMessage?chat_id=%7B-Variable.CHAT_ID-%7D&text=BLA_BLA&reply_markup=%7BSome_Keyboard%7D)

editing the text with the same above request (editMessageText) ends up with error:
"Bad Request: message can't be edited"

I've spent couple hours already trying different methods, including adding the same &reply_markup={Some_Keyboard} in the edited request, but get the same error.
I would be very appreciated to any suggestions what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also spent some time on this problem, and finally this can solve it

```
 bot.editMessageText("Choose!",{
      chat_id:chat_id,
      message_id:message_id,
      reply_markup:keyboard
    });
```